# How to split dataset for Time Series Data using caret package for R

Tags: r, time-series, cross-validation, caret

I have a dataset of many predictors including Individual and Year.  If I understand how the caret package works for creating folds, it randomly splits the dataset irrespective of variables.  The years start at 2004 and go to 2014.  There is at most one datapoint per individual per year, however the data is unbalanced and one individual may have datapoints for each year, or may have datapoints for just 1 year.  This varies throughout the dataset.

Should I, and how would I go about forcing caret in R to grab all of the records for one individual and placing it in one fold rather than randomly having a couple records from the same individual in different folds?  Some code and reference to where to find that code would be most helpful.

Comment: DId you see this? http://topepo.github.io/caret/splitting.html

Comment: Yes I did see that, but am not sure createtimeslices will work as my data is unbalanced.  I have not been able to find much to help explain createtimeslices and how to apply to this problem.